# Scala Map implementation keeping entries in insertion order?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.8, ordered-map

In Java, I use `LinkedHashMap` for this purpose. The documentation of Java's `LinkedHashMap` is very clear that it has "predictable iteration order" and I need the same in Scala.

Scala has `ListMap` and `LinkedHashMap`, but the documentation on what they do exactly is poor.

Question: Is Scala's `LinkedHashMap` or `ListMap` the implementation to use for this purpose? If not, what other options are available besides using the Java's `LinkedHashMap` directly?

Comment: just to note, I don't recommend using scala's ListMap classes in general. They have linear time complexity for most operations. So unless your map is tiny, logic that uses listmaps will really drag. http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html

Comment: Unfortunately, because `ListMap` is only immutable, it's also hard to "find" like if you make it part of another nested type even for a `val`, it needs to be imported explicitly. It's not clear to me why it isn't already in scope like `List` and `Map` are.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From the `LinkedHashMap` Scaladoc page:

- "This class implements mutable maps using a hashtable. The iterator and
  all traversal methods of this class visit elements in the order they were
  inserted."

Answer (score 19):

The difference between the two is that `LinkedHashMap` is mutable while `ListMap` is immutable. Otherwise they both are `MapLike` and also preserve insertion order.

Comment: There are both immutable ListMap and mutable ListMap.

Comment: other difference is that `ListMap` has [linear complexity in lookup and insertion](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html)

Answer (score 7):

For LinkedHashMap, the answer is pretty clear that it preserves the order of insertion.

But for ListMap, it seems that there are some confuses here.

Firstly, there are two ListMap.

- scala.collection.mutable.ListMap
- scala.collection.immutable.ListMap.

Secondly, the document for ListMap has something wrong as far as I tried.

[**mutable.ListMap**](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/mutable/ListMap.html)

**The actual order is not the insertion order as it says.**

And it is not the inverse order of insertion, either. The result I tried is [forth, second, first, third]

> A simple mutable map backed by a list, so it preserves insertion order.

[**immutable.ListMap**](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.html)

**As the document saying that, the order is the insertion order.**

One thing to notice is that it is stored internally in reversed insertion order. And the internally stored order and the iterable/traversal order are two things. The internally stored order decides the time complexity of lookup methods such as head/last/tail/init/.

> This class implements immutable maps using a list-based data structure. List map iterators and traversal methods visit key-value pairs in the order whey were first inserted.
>
> Entries are stored internally in reversed insertion order, which means the newest key is at the head of the list.

Comment: Interesting. Did you report the conflict between real and documented behaviour to authors? https://github.com/scala/bug  Edit: Seems someone did, and it's considered for deprecation in 2.13 https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9893

Answer (score 4):

`ListMap` doesn't preserves the order of insertion.

[image]

Only `LinkedHashMap` maintains the order of elements the way they are inserted.

[image]

If you want to maintain order in Lists otherthan Map you can use `LinkedList`

[image]

Comment: you're evaluating mutable listmaps but most people use the immutable listmaps which is a completely different implementation

Answer (score 4):

Scala 2.13 is introducing two new immutable implementations of `Map` which keep insertion order: `VectorMap` and `SeqMap`. See this [PR](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6854):

> Currently there isn't any known immutable map which also maintains key insertion order while keeping effectively constant lookup time on key, so the only known implementations are done by combining a Vector with a HasMap (or in Scala's case HashMap/ChampHashMap)

As of writing, Scala 2.13 is still scheduled to be released in 2018.

UPDATE 2021-04-14: Scala 3.13 does have [`VectorMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/VectorMap.html) now. [`SeqMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/SeqMap.html) is just a "generic trait for ordered immutable maps". Besides the new `VectorMap` and the older [`ListMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.html), there is also a new [`TreeSeqMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/TreeSeqMap$.html).

Note that [`mutable.ListMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ListMap.html) got deprecated with 2.13, but [`immutable.ListMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.html) is still current.

Answer (score 3):

- LinkedHashmap is in the order it was added
- (immutable) ListMap is in the backward order it was added (i.e. the last one added is first)

LinkedHashmap is only implemented as a mutable map
ListMaps are implemented in both the mutable and immutable packages, however only the immutable ListMaps maintain the backwards ordering. (mutable listmaps do not maintain order)

Comment: this is a nice article that breaks down the various map implementations in scala http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-choose-map-implementation-class-sorted-scala-cookbook

Comment: ListMap doesn't even maintain order in backward order as you are saying. It randomly displays from the list.

Comment: Actually the document of scala api is wrong. And it is different between immutable.ListMap and mutable.ListMap

Comment: @Nandakishore you are referring to mutable listmaps only. I've updated my answer to differentiate between the 2 types (mutable and immutable).

Comment: just wanted to note that both ListMaps implementations have slow time complexity for most functions so it reduces their practicality in using with large amounts of data. Unless mutability is an absolute deal killer, you should use LinkedHashmap