# scala map += operator with five pairs

Tags: scala, append, operators, ordered-map

I am having an issue with appending pairs to an existing Map. Once I reach the fifth pair of the Map, the Map reorders itself. The order is correct with 4 pairs, but as soon as the 5th is added it shifts itself. See example below (assuming I built the 4 pair Map one pair at a time.):

```
scala> val a = Map("a1" -> 1, "a2" -> 1, "a3" -> 1, "a4" -> 1)
a: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a1 -> 1, a2 -> 1, a3 -> 1, a4 -> 1)

scala> a += ("a5" -> 1)
scala> a
res26: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a5 -> 1, a4 -> 1, a3 -> 1, a1 -> 1, a2 -> 1)
```

The added fifth element jumped to the front of the Map and shifts the others around. Is there a way to keep the elements in order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to keep the insertion order, look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835743/scala-map-implementation-keeping-entries-in-insertion-order).

Answer (score 3):

By default Scala's `immutable.Map` uses `HashMap`.

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time

So a map is really not a table that contains `"a1" -> 1`, but a table that contains `hash("a1") -> 1`. The map reorders its keys based on the hash of the key rather than the key you put in it.

As was recommended in the comments, use `LinkedHashMap` or `ListMap`:
[Scala Map implementation keeping entries in insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835743/scala-map-implementation-keeping-entries-in-insertion-order)

PS: You might be interested in reading this article: http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/09/how-hashmap-works-in-java/