# Convert Array[(String,String)] to Map[String,String] keeping the order of keys in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to convert **Array[(String,String)]** to **Map[String,String]** in scala.

I am trying ***toMap*** to convert to map.

Problem : It is changing the order of values.

Expectation : Order should not be changed.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala Map implementation keeping entries in insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835743/scala-map-implementation-keeping-entries-in-insertion-order)

Comment: The question is nonsensical, because there is no such thing as `Array[String, String]`, at least not with the standard definition of `Array`.

Comment: It's also confusing to talk about order of values in a map which is an unordered data structure (apart from special implementations such as SortedMap).

Comment: Do you mean `Array[(String, String)]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work...

`LinkedHashMap` class implements mutable maps using a hashtable. The iterator and all traversal methods of this class visit elements in the order they were inserted.

```
scala> val arr = Array(("something","else"),("foo","a"),("bar","b"),("some","c"),("a1","b1"),("a2","b2"),("a3","b3"),("a4","b4"),("a5","b5"),("a6","c6"))
arr: Array[(String, String)] = Array((something,else), (foo,a), (bar,b), (some,c), (a1,b1), (a2,b2), (a3,b3), (a4,b4), (a5,b5), (a6,c6))

scala> val testMap =  scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,String]()
testMap: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,String] = Map()

arr.foreach(x=> testMap += (x._1 ->x._2))

scala> testMap
res1: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,String] = Map(something -> else, foo -> a, bar -> b, some -> c, a1 -> b1, a2 -> b2, a3 -> b3, a4 -> b4, a5 -> b5, a6 -> c6)
```

Answer (score 0):

**After Comments:**

It looks like the naive approach would not work in a sense that the order of the keys would be preserved. Here is a very useful test script from

[andrey-tyukin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2707792/andrey-tyukin)

```
  for (s <- 1 until 100) {
    val keys = (1 to s).map(_.toString).toList
    val arr: Array[(String, String)] = keys.map { x => (x, x) }.toArray
    val m = arr.toMap
    val newKeysOrder = m.map(_._1).toList println (s + ": " + (keys == newKeysOrder))
  }
```

Basically it shows that the this approach is no good.

```
Array(("foo","a"), ("bar", "b"), ("baz", "c")).toList.toMap
```

I would however advise to avoid mutable data structures.

**New Anser:**

I would just use another simple construct from `scala.collection.immutable.ListMap` :

```
val m = ListMap(arr:_*)
```

And here is a script that tests if it's o.k. basically it's true for first 100 ints

```
  for (s <- 1 until 100) {
    val keys = (1 to s).map(_.toString).toList
    val arr: Array[(String, String)] = keys.map { x => (x, x) }.toArray
    val m = ListMap(arr: _*)
    val newKeysOrder = m.keys.toList
    println(s + ": " + (keys == newKeysOrder))
  }
```

Comment: Please read the other answers and comments before answering. This does NOT preserve order as the OP requested. Edit: Since the other post has been deleted, you obviously can't check the other answers now. But try this out on a larger collection. You will see it does not preserve order

Comment: I did try on up to 10 items there and thought it's fine ... I'll have a look at larger collection, have to commute now will give it a look in the evening. It might also be wrong answer, as far as I tried it worked.

Comment: Try this. `val a = for (i <- 1 to 5; j <- 6 to 10) yield ("" + i, "" + j)` `val b = a.toList` `b.toMap` `res9: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(4 -> 10, 5 -> 10, 1 -> 10, 2 -> 10, 3 -> 10)` I think issues may occur when there are collisions

Comment: Here is another fun little script to experiment with, if you want: `for (s <- 1 until 100) {
  val keys = (1 to s).map(_.toString).toList
  val arr: Array[(String, String)] = keys.map{x => (x, x)}.toArray
  val m = arr.toMap
  val newKeysOrder = m.map(_._1).toList
  println(s + ": " + (keys == newKeysOrder))
}
` For this particular choice of keys, it seems to preserve the order for tiny maps of size up to `4`.

Comment: Thanks for providing the script :) at least I would like to avoid mutable then. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListMap which implements immutable maps by using a list-based data structure.

ListMap maintains insertion order and returns ListMap.

1.Create an array

```
 val arr=Array(("a","Alice"),("b","Bob"),("c","Cat"),("d","Dog"))
```

2.Create ListMap

```
import scala.collection.immutable._
val listMap=arr.foldLeft(ListMap[String,String]())((prev,next)=>prev+(next._1->next._2))
```

3.It will produce below output

```
listMap: scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[String,String] = Map(a -> Alice, b -> Bob, c -> Cat, d -> Dog)
```