# Why element order is not preserved when converting a list of pairs to Map in Scala?

Tags: scala

Example:

```
val occ = List(('l', 2), ('n', 1), ('r', 1), ('u', 2), ('x', 1))
occ.toMap
// Map(x -> 1, n -> 1, u -> 2, l -> 2, r -> 1)
```

The elements are no longer sorted in alphabetical order. Why does this happen?

Comment: @CannedMoose if we use sorted map then only it will sort the map by key it's not  the case always.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala Map implementation keeping entries in insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835743/scala-map-implementation-keeping-entries-in-insertion-order)

Comment: The question asked about a 'toMap' method in List, I see it is different with ListMap. And I do not find an answer in the question recommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Map`s are not sorted and the keys may be in any order depending on implementation.

However a `ListMap` preserves the order of addition. You can build a `ListMap` using the normal `Map` operations, or you can create one from a `List` like this:

```
ListMap(occ:_*)
```

Comment: I know there are ways to preserve the order. I am just curious why converting to map do not preserve the order. What is reason/concern in implementation the "toMap" method.

Comment: @EmmaLiu `toMap` just converts the `List` to a `Map`. It is the implementation of `Map` that matters. This is typically done with a table indexed by a hash of the key value (hence `HashMap`). The order of the keys will be the order of the hashed values, not the order of the keys themselves.

Comment: @EmmaLiu: A map *has no order*. It doesn't preserve the order *because there is no order to preserve*.

Comment: @Tim Your explanation answers my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: there's a `LinkedMap` coming in [2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6854) with different trade-offs.

Edit: the question is really that you might expect `list.toMap` to produce a `ListMap`. Why doesn't it?

The [doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.html) says "inserting or removing entries, are also O(n), which makes this collection suitable only for a small number of elements."

So that's another sensitivity to size. Often you create a collection as pairs resulting from other operations and you just want to dump them into a map, often a large one.

--

There is sensitivity to size due to specialization. There are custom maps for the smallest sizes. This isn't guaranteed, but is confusing if you notice the pattern.

```
scala $ ~/scala-2.12.6/bin/scala -Dscala.repl.info
Welcome to Scala 2.12.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_144).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
[info] started at Wed Jun 20 00:17:33 PDT 2018

scala 2.12.6> val m = List(1->10,2->20,3->30,4->40).toMap
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 10, 2 -> 20, 3 -> 30, 4 -> 40)

scala 2.12.6> val m = List(1->10,2->20,3->30,4->40,5->50).toMap
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(5 -> 50, 1 -> 10, 2 -> 20, 3 -> 30, 4 -> 40)

scala 2.12.6> :quit
scala $ ~/scala-2.13.0-M4/bin/scala -Dscala.repl.info
[info] started at Wed Jun 20 00:18:41 PDT 2018
Welcome to Scala 2.13.0-M4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_144).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala 2.13.0-M4> val m = List(1->10,2->20,3->30,4->40).toMap
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = ChampHashMap(1 -> 10, 2 -> 20, 3 -> 30, 4 -> 40)

scala 2.13.0-M4> val m = List(1->10,2->20,3->30,4->40,5->50).toMap
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = ChampHashMap(5 -> 50, 1 -> 10, 2 -> 20, 3 -> 30, 4 -> 40)
```

Comment: Yes, I do noticed this. For very small maps, the conversion keeps the element in order. But for slightly larger map, the order is not longer preserved, but determined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ListMap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.html) instead of Map, it keeps items in the order they were inserted. To convert `List` to `ListMap`:

```
val occ = List(('l', 2), ('n', 1), ('r', 1), ('u', 2), ('x', 1))
ListMap(occ: _*)
```

In case you don't know what `_*` means - [repeated parameters](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#repeated-parameters)